# Accounting for gender differences between two groups

Tags: spss

I have 2 separate groups of patients and I'm comparing frequency of attendance in either group. I would like to perform an analysis that accounts for gender as a separate variable but I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is. I did a linear regression but not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Can you describe your goals in more detail? What conclusion are you trying to reach? If you'd like to ask about interpreting the output of your regression table, then posting the table would likely be helpful as well asking something specific about that output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have three variables:

```
Dependent variable: Attendance
Independent variable 1: Group (2 levels)
Independent variable 2: Gender (2 levels)
```

Just FYI: This can be formalized as either  a factorial analysis of variance or a regression, and it does not really matter, because the results will be the same.

I would suggest doing the following in SPSS:

```
- Click Analysis -> Generalized Linear Model (GLM) -> Univariate
- Add Attendance as the dependent variable
- Add Group and Gender as fixed effects
- Click on model and choose saturated model -> Continue
- Click on Plots
- Add Gender to separate lines and Group to horizontal axis
- Continue and run
```

The output will provide you with:

```
- Main effects of Group and Gender
- The interaction effect of Group and Gender
- A plot so that you can make sense of it
```

Disclaimer: This is a bare-bones description and I highly recommend you to do some reading yourself about the basics of statistical testing, assumptions that have to be met for statistical tests etc. Just because the program says it's significant (or not) does not mean the results actually make sense!